# Many years ago, (45 years or more) I read a book about a tin can shaped space station

Tags: story-identification, space-station

Novel years ago, tin can shaped space station, different levels were color coded to indicate the different "gravity" on that floor.  They built the station by building a space wheel, then another, then building "tin can" walls between them with the space wheels acting as the ends of the can.  As I remember, a "space cadet moving through the ranks" kind of a plot

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a pretty common description / design of a space station. We really need more data.

Comment: I disagree with closing this; most spun stations are wheels (think *2001*); most cylindrical stations are O'Neill habitats with only 1 main gravity zone (like *Rama*) and the colour-coded levels is unusual.

Comment: out of curiosity, was that space cadet the winner of a contest, and the station counted as being "on earth" due to its lower orbit?

Comment: I only remember snippets.  Different colored floors to represent levels.  Yellow indicated danger areas (I can’t remember if danger areas were zero g or max g). The elevator was yellow, our cadet asked why elevator was yellow, upper class men said it was dangerous if a cadet got caught using the elevator without permission.  The upperclassman challenged the cadet to identify what level the elevator was on with his back to the elevator door, cadet identified 19 out of 20 stops correctly.  It is bugging me that I can’t remember how the story ends.

Comment: I don’t think it was a contest win, but possible? I suppose.

Comment: Michael was hinting at Clarke's *Islands in the Sky* but only the Residential Station is a possible match, it was only at the end of the book and there are only 3 levels.  No colour coding and the young man is not a cadet.

Comment: @DavidW that is the one I was hinting at, and thank you for finding its title.  This question actually made me think of asking to find that book, since I vividly remember the story but not the title :-)

Comment: Remembered one other snippet.  The cadet found out he had been promoted from cadet status by coming in to his room and seeing a new stack of folded uniform, different (style? color?) than his cadet uniform.  His first thought is that his roommate was playing a prank on him.

Comment: I wonder if it's "Step to the Stars" by Lester Del Rey - which was much more military-oriented than the Clarke.

Comment: It was a great suggestion, but I checked online and not the plot.  Pity, because Lester Del Rey was one of the earliest Sci Fi  I  read as a child. (Runaway robot). But thank you for the possibility.